# Slope coefficients of Interaction between two categories and continuous variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data

If I have the following regression model:
Where wage is a continuous dependent variable and working hours is a sole continuous independent variable.
Sex is a categorical variable (two categories: male and female) =1 if male and 0 if female

Marital status is a categorical variable (three categories: divorced, single and married), Marital status1 =1 if single and 0 otherwise and Marital status2 =1 if married and 0 otherwise

There are interaction terms between sex and Marital status as follows
Sex* Marital status1 and
Sex* Marital status2

I used intercept and slope dummies

This is the model
Wage = 0 + 1 sex + 2 Marital status1 + 3 Marital status2 + 4 (sex* Marital status1) + 5 (sex* Marital status2) + C0 working hours + C1 working hours * sex + C2 working hours * Marital status1 + C3 working hours * Marital status2 + C4 working hours * (sex* Marital status1) + C5 working hours * (sex* Marital status2) + e

I am interested in slope coefficients
My questions
Is this model correct?
How I interpret C4 and C5 (assuming that each is significantly positive)?

Comment: What's your primary variable of interest? Are you comfortable with derivatives?